# Hex grid map with PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I am trying to create a map editor. I intend the map to be an hexagonal grid where each hexagon is a tile of the map. A tile will be a graphical representation of that area (sea, meadow, desert, mountain, etc). The map is intended to be of any size. Let's freeze the requirements here for now :)

I want to use PyQt4 (take it as a design requirement). As I am just starting with Qt/PyQt, I am facing the problem of vastness: so big this Qt thing that I cannot grasp it all. And here I am, asking for your kind and most welcome experience.

After a bit of googling, I've decided to use the QGraphicalView/Scene approach. In fact, I was thinking about creating my own hexgrid class inheriting from QGraphicalView and creating my RegularPolygon class inheriting from QGraphicalPolygonItem.

Now they come the doubts and problems.

My main doubt is "Is my approach a correct one?" Think about the needs I have explained at the beginning of the post: hexagonal map, where each hexagon will be a tile of a given type (sea, desert, meadows, mountains, etc). I am concerned about performance once the editor works (scrolling will feel nice? and this kind of things).

And so far, the problem is about precision. I am drawing the hexgrid by creating and drawing all its hexagons (this even sounds bad to me... thinking about performance). I used some formulas to calculate the vertices of each hexagon and creating the polygon from there. I expect the sides of two consecutive hexagons to coincide exactly at the same location, but the rounding seems to be playing a bit with my desires, as sometimes the hexagon sides perfectly matches in the same location (good) and sometimes they do not match by what seems to be 1 pixel difference (bad). This gives a poor visual impression of the grid. Maybe I have not explained myself quite well... it's better if I give you the code and you run it by yourselves

So summarizing:

1. Do you think my approach will give future performance issues?
2. Why are not the hexagons placed exactly so that they share sides? How to avoid this problem?

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""
Editor of the map.
"""

__meta__ =  \
{
    (0,0,1): (
              [ "Creation" ],
              [ ("Victor Garcia","vichor@xxxxxxx.xxx") ]
             )
} 

import sys, math
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

# ==============================================================================
class HexGrid(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    """
    Graphics view for an hex grid.
    """

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, rect=None, parent=None):
        """
        Initializes an hex grid. This object will be a GraphicsView and it will
        also handle its corresponding GraphicsScene.
            rect -- rectangle for the graphics scene.
            parent -- parent widget
        """
        super(HexGrid,self).__init__(parent)

        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        if rect != None: 
            if isinstance(rect, QtCore.QRectF): self.scene.setSceneRect(rect)
            else: raise StandardError ('Parameter rect should be QtCore.QRectF')
        self.setScene(self.scene)

# ==============================================================================
class QRegularPolygon(QtGui.QGraphicsPolygonItem):
    """
    Regular polygon of N sides
    """

    def __init__(self, sides, radius, center, angle = None, parent=None):
        """
        Initializes an hexagon of the given radius.
            sides -- sides of the regular polygon
            radius -- radius of the external circle
            center -- QPointF containing the center
            angle -- offset angle in radians for the vertices
        """
        super(QRegularPolygon,self).__init__(parent)

        if sides < 3: 
            raise StandardError ('A regular polygon at least has 3 sides.')
        self._sides = sides
        self._radius = radius
        if angle != None: self._angle = angle
        else: self._angle = 0.0
        self._center = center

        points = list()
        for s in range(self._sides):
            angle = self._angle + (2*math.pi * s/self._sides)
            x = center.x() + (radius * math.cos(angle))
            y = center.y() + (radius * math.sin(angle))
            points.append(QtCore.QPointF(x,y))

        self.setPolygon( QtGui.QPolygonF(points) )


# ==============================================================================
def main():
    """
    That's it: the  main function
    """
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    grid = HexGrid(QtCore.QRectF(0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 500.0))

    radius = 50
    sides = 6

    apothem = radius * math.cos(math.pi/sides)
    side = 2 * apothem * math.tan(math.pi/sides)

    xinit = 50
    yinit = 50
    angle = math.pi/2
    polygons = list()

    for x in range(xinit,xinit+20):
        timesx = x - xinit
        xcenter = x + (2*apothem)*timesx
        for y in range(yinit, yinit+20):
            timesy = y - yinit
            ycenter = y + ((2*radius)+side)*timesy

            center1 = QtCore.QPointF(xcenter,ycenter)
            center2 = QtCore.QPointF(xcenter+apothem,ycenter+radius+(side/2))

            h1 = QRegularPolygon(sides, radius, center1, angle)
            h2 = QRegularPolygon(sides, radius, center2, angle)

            # adding polygons to a list to avoid losing them when outside the
            # scope (loop?). Anyway, just in case
            polygons.append(h1)
            polygons.append(h2)

            grid.scene.addItem(h1)
            grid.scene.addItem(h2)

    grid.show()
    app.exec_()

# ==============================================================================
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and last but not least, sorry for the long post :)

Thanks
Victor

Comment: I have found http://www.pygame.org/ with examples of hexgrids, but they are not using PyQt. I will take a look at it, definitely, but my question is still valid, as I want to know how to do the hexmap correctly using qt.

Comment: I will try a different approach. Drawing all the hexagons means that several vertices will be drawn two times (the ones shared by two hexagons). This sounds stupid: why do the same job twice? I will try drawing the first hexagon (top left? maybe the starting by the one in the center of the scene?). To drive the second one I will just need to draw the vertices pending to be drawn, and so on. This will ensure that the shared vertices are in the exact same pixel, solving my precision problem. Luckily, it will also avoid future performance issues... it will take me a while to do this, though.

Comment: Just a hint for click-region identification, use 2 rectangles for rough analysis (external boundaries, internal boundaries) and if needed (click in overlapping area of external boundaries) calculate which hex is activated (if not solved with sceneitem-mouseevents).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @Sebastian Lange, but unfortunately, I am still far away of suffering this click-regio identification problem as I am still blocked at drawing nicely the hexes on the grid. Due to floating point vs. integer precission, some adjacent hexe have 1-pixel wide gap between them, creating a poor visual impression. I still have to fight with the idea of my previous comment. If you have a better approach, I would gladly hear about it.

Comment: "The map can be of any size". Eventually there is your problem. The map should always be n-times the size of a single hex. This way you would not have rounded numbers. If you definitly need to have a dynamic size, expand the map to be n-times the size of a single hex outside of view. This way you can still cleanly draw your hex, but have a "half row" at the end (full row, but only half visible in view). So actually make the map n-times the size of a hex, but make the view only show your desired map size.

Comment: That's a good idea, but it won't solve the problem. If you check the code I pasted in my question, you will see that a hexagon location is determined by adding the aphotem to the center of the previous hex. The center of the previous hex maybe something like (6.45,7) and the apothem also some float number. When going to draw, the coords get rounded to int and that's when the problem appears. This may happen regardless the size of the map. So the problem is the way I am generating the coords to place the center of each hex, but I cannot think of other ways to generate the. I'm quite stuck at it

Comment: Would it help, if you are adding the increment to the rounded center? this way, every new hex would have the same small error and could be fixed?

Comment: I think that you should separate the mathematics of the hex grid from the frontend. I mean PyQt does not have to know about your grid. It only has to know about the points/lines/whatever to draw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd define each hexagonal tile as a separate SVG image, and use QImage and QSvgRenderer classes to render them to QPixmaps (with an alpha channel) whenever the zoom level changes. I'd create a QGraphicsItem subclass for displaying each tile.

The trick is to pick the zoom level so that the width of the (upright) hexagon is a multiple of two, and the height a multiple of four, with width/height approximately sqrt(3/4). The hexagons are slightly squished in either direction, but for all hexagons at least eight pixels in diameter, the effect is inperceptible.

If the width of the hexagon is `2*w`, and height `4*h`, here's how to map the (upright) hexagons to Cartesian coordinates:

[image: Hexagon in a rectangular grid]

If each side of the hexagon is `a`, then `h=a/2` and `w=a*sqrt(3)/2`, therefore `w/h=sqrt(3)`.

For optimum display quality, pick integer `w` and `h`, so that their ratio is approximately `sqrt(3) ≃ 1.732`. This means your hexagons will be very slightly squished, but that's okay; it is not perceptible.

Because the coordinates are now always integers, you can safely (without display artefacts) use pre-rendered hexagon tiles, as long as they have an alpha channel, and perhaps a border to allow smoother alpha transitions. Each rectangular tile is then `2*w+2*b` pixels wide and `4*h+2*b` pixels tall, where `b` is the number of extra border (overlapping) pixels.

The extra border is needed to avoid perceptible seams (background color bleeding through) where pixels are only partially opaque in all overlapping tiles. The border allows you to better blend the tile into the neighboring tile; something the SVG renderer will do automatically if you include a small border region in your SVG tiles.

If you use typical screen coordinates where `x` grows right and `y` down, then the coordinates for hexagon `X,Y` relative to the `0,0` one are trivial:

```
y = 3*h*Y
if Y is even, then:
    x = 2*w*X
else:
    x = 2*w*X + w
```

Obviously, odd rows of hexagons are positioned half a hexagon to the right.

Subclassing QGraphicsItem and using a bounding polygon (for mouse and interaction tests) means Qt will do all the heavy work for you, when you wish to know which hexagonal tile the mouse is hovering on top of.

However, you *can* do the inverse mapping -- from screen coordinates back to hexagons -- yourself.

First, you calculate which rectangular grid cell (green grid lines in the image above) the coordinate pair is in:

```
u = int(x / w)
v = int(y / h)
```

Let's assume all coordinates are nonnegative. Otherwise, `%` must be read as *"nonnegative remainder, when divided by"*. (That is, `0 <= a % b < b` for all `a`, even negative `a`; `b` is always a positive integer here.)

If the origin is as shown in the above image, then two rows out of every three are trivial, except that every odd row of hexagons is shifted one grid cell right:

```
if v % 3 >= 1:
    if v % 6 >= 4:
        X = int((u - 1) / 2)
        Y = int(v / 3)
    else:
        X = int(u / 2)
        Y = int(v / 3)
```

Every third row contains rectangular grid cells with a diagonal boundary, but worry not: if the boundary is `\` (wrt. above image), you only need to check if

```
    (x % w) * h   >=   (y % h) * w
```

to find out if you are in the upper right triangular part. If the boundary is `/` wrt. above image, you only need to check if

```
    (x % w) * h + (y % h) * w   >=   (w * h - (w + h) / 2)
```

to find out if you are in the lower right triangular part.

In each four-column and six-row section of rectangular grid cells, there are eight cases that need to be handled, using one of the above test clauses. (I'm too lazy to work the exact if clauses for you here; like I said, I'd let Qt do that for me.) This rectangular region repeats exactly for the entire hexagonal map; thus, a full coordinate conversion may need up to 9 if clauses (depending on how you write it), so it's a bit annoying to write.

If you wish to determine e.g. the mouse cursor location relative to the hexagon it is hovering over, first use the above to determine which hexagon the mouse hovers over, then substract the coordinates of that hexagon from the mouse coordinates to get the coordinates relative to the current hexagon.

Comment: Wonderful. I will test it this very next week. I will anyway close the question and grant the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: @victor: I'm happy to help. I noticed I had the `/` and `\ ` diagonal boundary tests swapped; fixed now. If you or others find any other typos or errors, please pipe up. The logic is sound, only my explanation above may contain typos or errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this main() function. I used the radius of the inscribed circle (ri) instead of the circumscribed circle that you used (radius). It looks a bit better now, but still not perfect. I think the way the oblique sides are drawn at the top and bottom of the hexagon are different.

```
def main():
    """
    That's it: the  main function
    """
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    grid = HexGrid(QtCore.QRectF(0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 500.0))

    radius = 50 # circumscribed circle radius
    ri = int(radius / 2 * math.sqrt(3)) # inscribed circle radius
    sides = 6

    apothem = int(ri * math.cos(math.pi/sides))
    side = int(2 * apothem * math.tan(math.pi/sides))

    xinit = 50
    yinit = 50
    angle = math.pi/2
    polygons = list()

    for x in range(xinit,xinit+20):
        timesx = x - xinit
        xcenter = x + (2*apothem-1)*timesx
        for y in range(yinit, yinit+20):
            timesy = y - yinit
            ycenter = y + ((2*ri)+side)*timesy

            center1 = QtCore.QPointF(xcenter,ycenter)
            center2 = QtCore.QPointF(xcenter+apothem,ycenter+ri+(side/2))

            h1 = QRegularPolygon(sides, ri, center1, angle)
            h2 = QRegularPolygon(sides, ri, center2, angle)

            # adding polygons to a list to avoid losing them when outside the
            # scope (loop?). Anyway, just in case
            polygons.append(h1)
            polygons.append(h2)

            grid.scene.addItem(h1)
            grid.scene.addItem(h2)

    grid.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems here.  They aren't specifically related to Qt or to Python, but to general computer science.

You have floating point geometrical shapes that you want to display on a raster device, so  somehow there has to be a floating point to integer conversion.  It's not in your code, so it will happen at a lower level: in the graphics library, the display driver or whatever.  Since you're not happy with the result, you have to handle this conversion yourself.

There's no right or wrong way to do this.  For example, take your case of a hex tile that has a “radius” of 50.  The hexagon is oriented so that the W vertex is at (-50,0) and the E vertex is at (50,0).  Now the NE vertex of this hexagon is at approximately (25,0,43.3).  The hexagon that's adjacent to this one in the N direction has its center at about y=86.6 and its top edge at 129.9.  How would you like to pixellate this?  If you round 43.3 down to 43, now you no longer have a mathematically exact regular hexagon.  If you round 129.9 up to 130, your first hexagon is 86 pixels in total height but the one on top of it is 87.  This is an issue that you must resolve based on the project's requirements.

And this is just one case (radius=50).  If you allow the radius to be variable, can you come up with an algorithm to handle all cases?  I couldn't.  I think you need to use a fixed screen dimension for your hexagons, or at least reduce the possibilities to a small number.

Nowhere in your code do you determine the size of the display window, so I don't understand how you intend to handle scaling issues, or determine how many hexes are needed to show the full map.

As to your first question, I am certain that the performance will be poor.  The constructor for QRegularPolygon is inside the loop that creates the hexes, so it gets called many times (800 in your example).  It does two trig calculations for each vertex, so you perform 9600 trig calculations as you build your list of hexes.  You don't need ANY of them.  The calculations are the sine and cosine of 0 degrees, 60 degrees, 120 degrees and so on.  Those are so easy you don't even need sin and cos.

The use of the trig functions exacerbates the floating point/integer problem, too.  Look at this:

```
>> int(50.0*math.sin(math.pi/6)) 
24
```

We know it should be 25, but the computer figures it as int(24.999999999996) – I may have left out a few 9's.

If you calculate the vertex positions of just one hexagon, you can get all the other ones by a simple translation.  See the useful Qt functions QPolygon->translate or QPolygon->translated.

It seems that you don't need a constructor that can handle any type of polygon when your design concept absolutely needs hexagons.  Did you just copy it from somewhere?  I think it's mostly clutter, which always opens the door to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need polygons here? Later on, I suppose, the game will use raster images, so the polygons are just for display purposes. 
You could just take a point cloud representing all corners of the polygon and draw lines beneath them. With this, you avoid problems of rounding / floating point arithmetics etc.

Comment: That's similar to the approach I expressed in my own comment on the post starting with "I will try a different approach". Just I don't know how to get the point cloud. As I'm working on python, I was expecting to create a dictionary using world coordinates as key and a list of terrain properties, items and other stuff as value for the given key. So, under a modeling point of view, everything is clear. My problems start when I try to draw that model, I cannot figure out how to perform this transformation. Comment from @Paul Cornelius is quite near to the actual situation I am facing.